# UnboundLocalError in __init__

Tags: python, oop, constructor, init

I begin to study python and cant understand, where is error

```
class Gun(object):
    def __init__(self, magazine=6):
        self.__dict__["magazine"] = magazine
        self.__dict__["ammo"] = ammo
```

error log

```
self.__dict__["ammo"] = ammo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ammo' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your `__init__` arguments. There's no `ammo` in the argument definition.

Try the following:

```
class Gun(object):
    def __init__(self, magazine=6, ammo=5): # Now there is!
        self.__dict__["magazine"] = magazine
        self.__dict__["ammo"] = ammo
```

I would advice against modifying the objects `__dict__`. Just create an instance variable, they do the same thing but the code is far more readable.

```
class Gun(object):
    def __init__(self, magazine=6, ammo=5):
        self.magazine = magazine
        self.ammo = ammo

In [3]: gun = Gun()

In [4]: gun.ammo
Out[4]: 5

In [5]: gun.magazine
Out[5]: 6
```

And of course, you should read the [official tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such variable as `ammo`. You are only passing `magazine` which is why it has no problem with the `magazine` line. Try this instead:

```
class Gun(object):
    def __init__(self, magazine=6, ammo=10):
        self.__dict__["magazine"] = magazine
        self.__dict__["ammo"] = ammo
```